# Hide-unhide feature grid in opengeo suite sdk myviewer

Tags: boundless-suite, geoexplorer

is there any way to hide-unhide the feature grid in opengeo suite custom viewer. In geoexplorer this is a default function.

Comment: Are you referring to the ability to collapse the panel with the little arrow? Or something else? This is standard Ext JS functionality.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do that. There is a plugin in opengeo suit sdk called FeatureGrid.js. If I change the code to: autoCollapse: true,
autoExpand: true,
nothing happening...

Comment: You should do it at the panel level instead see: https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite/blob/master/geoexplorer/app/static/script/app/GeoExplorer/Composer.js#L425:L427